# easy Slider 1.7 (Pause hover)

Tags: jquery-hover, mousehover, easyslider

I have a problem , i am using easy Slider 1.7 and i have a problem on Pause  Hover the element .
THe pause hover works , but not as i want it to .
As you can see in this example at the top of the page http://www.graphicvision.ro/projects/forex/index.php , the slider pause on mouse hover , for example hover the image or the text , but if i move it from the element (say text) to the image element. it plays the next slide even i am in the slider .  i want it when hover any element in the slider to stay paused .

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code worked perfectly fine for me as I just didnt want to pause the regular way, I wanted to pause the slider and keep the mouse moving within the element without being driven to the next slide. If you need assistance, please feel free to ask.

```
    if (options.hoverpause && options.auto){
    $('#slider').hover(function(){
            clearTimeout(timeout); 
    },function(){
    animate("next",false);
    });
    };
```